# Casting from a Task<IEnumerable<X>> to a Task<IEnumerable<Y>>

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to cast a list of items from one object to another as follows:

```cs
public async Task<IEnumerable<TaskDetailsEntity>> GetTaskDetails(int personnelSK)
{            
   /* 
   IEnumerable<TaskDetailsEntity> TaskDetailsEntitiesList = 
      await GetKTaskDetails(personnelSK).Select(
                               a => (KTaskDetailsEntity)a).ToList();
   */
   IEnumerable<TaskDetailsEntity> TaskDetailsEntitiesList = 
         await GetKTaskDetails(personnelSK).Cast<KTaskDetailsEntity>().ToList();
            
   return TaskDetailsEntitiesList;
}


public async Task<IEnumerable<KTaskDetailsEntity>> GetKTaskDetails(int personnelSK)
{
   List<ParameterInfo> parameters = new List<ParameterInfo>();                      
   if (personnelSK != 0)
   {
      parameters.Add(new ParameterInfo(){ 
             ParameterName = "@PI_PERSONNEL_SK"
             , ParameterValue = personnelSK });
    }
    IEnumerable<KTaskDetailsEntity> KTaskDetailsEntitiesList =
            await _SQLHelper.GetRecords<KTaskDetailsEntity>(
                             "[xx].[GET_TASK_DATA]"
                             , parameters);          
    return KTaskDetailsEntitiesList;
}
```

But with this, I'm getting below error in the 1st method:

> `'Task<IEnumerable<KTaskDetailsEntity>>'` does not contain a definition for 'Cast' and no accessible extension method 'Cast' accepting a first argument of type `'Task<IEnumerable<KTaskDetailsEntity>>'` could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: It's rather pointless to create a wrapper that just casts/converts the return value to another type. Let the callee deal with that.

Comment: The exception you have is that you have to wrap this part: `( await GetKTaskDetails(personnelSK) ).Cast...`. But I notice you are casting `KTaskDetailsEntity` to `TaskDetailsEntity`. Does `KTaskDetailsEntity` inherit from `TaskDetailsEntity`? If they are 2 distinct classes, you will get `InvalidCastException`...in such case you need a mapper. E.x: Automapper

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap with braces your `await`-ed result:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<TaskDetailsEntity>> GetTaskDetails(int personnelSK)
{            
    //IEnumerable<TaskDetailsEntity> TaskDetailsEntitiesList = await GetKTaskDetails(personnelSK).Select(a => (KTaskDetailsEntity)a).ToList();
    IEnumerable<TaskDetailsEntity> TaskDetailsEntitiesList = (await GetKTaskDetails(personnelSK)).Cast<TaskDetailsEntity>().ToList();
    
    return TaskDetailsEntitiesList;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Actually no need in `Cast<>` call here due to `IEnumerable<T>` covariance, so, final one is:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<TaskDetailsEntity>>GetTaskDetails(int personnelSK)
{        
  return (await GetKTaskDetails(personnelSK)).ToList();
}
```